# LoadRunner 12.5: Controller and Analysis tools returning inconsistent stats. Why?

Tags: loadrunner

I'm doing load testing with LoadRunner 12.5. This is installed on a Windows Server 2012(R2) VM (8Gb RAM). The particular test-suite uses only the HTTP and Oracle 2-tier protocols.

Full version details:

- LR Controller: 12.50.0.0 build 249
- LR Analyser: 12.50.0.0 build 1096
- no installed patches
- One loadgenerator running on the same host

**Problem:**

Following one 5day run, I've noticed that the Controller and Analysis transaction statistics differ - and quite considerably.

On completion of the LR Controller run, it reports my run stats as:

```
passed transactions = 937,946
failed transactions = 62
```

On generating the stats in LR Analysis, that reports my run stats as:

```
passed transactions = 1,019,158  (!)
failed transactions = 9,919  (!!)
```

Also, the Throughput graph (and Hits per second) are somewhat inconsistent between the applications, even accounting for the different graph scales.

Then, though this is obviously a contributing factor too the overall transaction counts already mentioned above, looking at individual transactions (e.g. transX, etc), I see:

```
Controller:  transX passed=249586, fail=11
Analysis:    transX passed=274063, fail=684

Controller:  transY passed=5224, fail=1
Analysis:    transY passed=5727, fail=665

Controller:  transZ passed=5227, fail=0
Analysis:    transZ passed=5756, fail=0
```

1. Any, any, any ideas why I'm seeing inconsistent transaction stats between Controller and Analysis?
2. Has Controller somehow not updated its own stats on completion? It is consistently lower than Analysis.

I shall delve into the .mdb to try and understand this further but tips/ assurances I'm not going crazy most welcome.

Related google question: [Discrepancies between final values recorded in Controller, and values in Analysis](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/lr-loadrunner/1AThGteAYUc/xLcorXT1AQAJ)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered the fix that made things pretty much identical in Analysis with the final values in Controller:

At the far lower left of the Analysis screen, are the words "Summary Data" with a downward-pointing triangle. Click the triangle and select "Generate Complete Data." Running this requires you keep around the Result directory created during the run, so if you've wiped those out it won't work. I'm not sure when that was introduced, but either it's reasonably new, or else the Summary data back in the 11.0x days was a lot closer to what the Controller reported.

Comment: Hi Rick, thanks for getting back to me. Bizzarely, still haven't resolved this. Been chatting to HP but it seems related to how failures are wrapped up in the summary count. They should be discounted apparently but that doesn't seem to stack up when my figures in Analysis are (far) larger than in Controller. I think Complete Data has been around a while (9.5 at least) but I've never really needed to use it before and Summary stats always seemed in-sync. I'm playing around with filters at the mo to rectify this. I'll keep you posted.

Comment: Hi again. This is indeed the issue. I've used LR 9.5 - LR 11.5 and never seen the need to generate the complete data. The LR Analysis stats have always matched the Controller stats. In my case, the difference was really large (64fails to 990000). Generating complete data does indeed correct the issue.

Comment: Couple of points to note in addition to this: 1) Generating complete data requires sufficient memory on your hardware. That is, we have a 6Gb .eve fine in the lrr location and this needs to beloaded fully into memory (no streaming). 2) The transaction times were slightly out between Controller and Analysis too but this is because Analysis omits "wasted time" - which includes any think-times you happen to (wrongly have) in your transaction times. It also includes other timings. You can correct this by configuring Analysis to not "ignore think times".

Answer (score 1):

Start with your VM.  Unless your are running VMWARE and have the settings to pin your load generator clock to the hypervisor OS clock, then you are going to get inconsistent timing records due to clock float and synch issues within the VM.

Also, since you are running on a virtual machine, you have the issues with consistent initial and in test conditions because you cannot control the behavior of the other virtual machines and how the hypervisor is brokering the resources that are shared with your load generator virtual machines and the rest of the virtual machines on the host in question.

How many load generators?  You do not mention any.  Should I assume that you are running all of your virtual users on the same host as the controller?  If so, Bad Magic!

The issues on virtual machines are well known and have been discussed many times over the past decade in online forums.  These are tool agnostic issues which impact all vendor performance testing tools.

Do you have a control load generator?  A physical host upon which you are running a single virtual user of each type?  Is this control data set consistent from one test to the next?

Comment: Thanks James for your response. I was unaware of issues with running it from a VM, so that is a bit of a concern. We have done so in the past without issue - and I believe it's the first time we've noticed it during our recent test. You mention that the loadgenerator timings will be inconsistent but the main issue we're seeing is inconsistency in the number of transactions (a significant difference). Would that also be likely when running in a VM?

Comment: To answer your questions: 1) load generators: We are using only a single load generator - this particular test just runs 8 users. 2) loadrunner host: This is the same host as the Controller. 3) control load: We do not have a separate physical set up. Our shorter performance tests on the VM were producing reasonable consistent results and (as far as I'm aware) did not show the transaction consistency. Thanks again...

Comment: I am going to chalk the number of timing records up to a difference from one run to the next in the number of resource cycles you get arbitrated from the hypervisor on your VM host.  You really have very little control of this in a shared environment.   Toss in heavy use by another VM for an arbitrated resource and one of you has to lose the arbitration battle.  The same people who mandate you use virtual machine load generators will complain about the consistency of your test resources.  They need to complain to the person in the mirror.